# Set npm package to save version with caret (^)

Tags: npm, package.json, semantic-versioning

When I `$ npm install eslint --savedev`, it produces this entry in my `package.json` file:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^3.9.1"
}
```

Notice the caret before the version number. When I install a package I've published in the same way `$ npm install @jsejcksn/eslint-config --savedev`, it does not add the caret:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@jsejcksn/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
  "eslint": "^3.9.1"
}
```

What do I need to do in order to get npm to save my package with the caret so it will allow major version updates of my package?

Comment: What is the output of `npm config get save-prefix`?

Comment: @RyanZim Just `^`

Comment: OK, no idea then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004:

> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the `[major, minor, patch]` tuple. In other words, this allows patch and minor updates for versions `1.0.0` and above, patch updates for versions `0.X >=0.1.0`, and *no* updates for versions `0.0.X`.

I incremented the version to 1.0.0 and it worked as expected.